# MYSQL rows show as JSON using php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have mysql table with several rows,
I want get JSON output something like this:

```
     {
"contacts": [
    {
            "id": "c200",
            "name": "Ravi Tamada",
            "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
    },
    {
            "id": "c201",
            "name": "Johnny Depp",
            "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
    },
    {
            "id": "c202",
            "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
            "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",

    },

] }
```

How I can get like this result using PHP ?

Comment: Put the results in an array, call `json_encode()`

Comment: I have put, but I can not generate main bracket, I want all rows under main brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your row data in an array you can do something like this: `json_encode(array('contacts' => $contacts))`

Comment: Show me full version

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to build your array as usual in PHP, once you have it just use the PHP function **json_encode()**, and you're done!

Comment: I build array, but I can not generate main brackets.